# How to index Azure storage data to elastic cloud

Tags: elasticsearch, azure-blob-storage, nest, azure-table-storage

I am new to elastic search. I have data stored in Azure storage and I want to index it using elasticsearch. I have created a cluster at https://cloud.elastic.co. Do I need to create a service which will index the data in elastic cloud and then users can use/search this data using elastic search? How to index the data to elastic cloud using asp.net MVC?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 7):

One way to approach this would be to write a console application that

1. pulls data from Azure storage using the Storage client in the  [`WindowsAzure.Storage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage?view=azure-dotnet) nuget package or similar
2. transforms data into documents according to your domain needs
3. bulk indexes documents into Elasticsearch in Elastic Cloud using the [.NET Elasticsearch client NEST](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net)

If data will be updated in Azure storage and will need to be frequently indexed into Elasticsearch, consider making the console application an [Azure Web Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs).

Another approach would be to use [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) in conjunction with the [input plugin for Azure Storage blobs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-diagnostics-tools/tree/master/Logstash/logstash-input-azureblob).